# How to put "and" and "or" condition in RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, url, mod-rewrite

This is my current `VirtualHost` node :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.com
  ServerAlias abc.com www.abc.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

It conveys that every request:80 coming to this server will redirect to `HTTPS`. Now i want to add `or` and `and` condition to `VirtualHost` node. So, that it will work as follow:

- If request:80 coming from xyz.com then it will not redirect to `HTTPS`
- If request:80 coming from abc.com then it will redirect to `HTTPS`

How should i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,R,L]
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to enforce https for avc.com